# How to remove selected commit log entries from a Git repository while keeping their changes?

Tags: git, commit

I would like to remove selected commit log entries from a linear commit tree, so that the entries do not show in the commit log.

My commit tree looks something like:

```
R--A--B--C--D--E--HEAD
```

I would like to remove the B and C entries so that they do not show in the commit log, but changes from A to D should be preserved. Maybe by introducing a single commit, so that B and C become BC and the tree looks like.

```
R--A--BC--D--E--HEAD
```

Or, ideally, after A comes D directly. D' representing changes from A to B, B to C and C to D.

```
R--A--D'--E--HEAD
```

Is this possible? if yes, how?

This is a fairly new project so has no branches as of now, hence no merges as well.

Comment: @xk0der: "commits" is the right term here. `rebase` may remove old/create new commits. I don't know what "commit log entries" means.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I don't see a problem with "commit log" - Log of all the commits. And I wanted to delete a few entries from the log - while keeping the actual changes (the commits).

Comment: @xk0der: [git commits are content-addressable](http://git-scm.com/book/ch9-2.html) i.e., if you change *anything* in a commit e.g., its log message; you create a new commit. You could [read git's commit without git and see for yourself](https://gist.github.com/754cdf6540f8ed7c4e56).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - Thanks for the links - I know that - But does that technicality really change the problem I was facing and how I put it forth? I guess not. In the end: I wanted to remove "the commit log messages" - without removing the "commit changes" - Please reread my question - specially the second paragraph. To add more `git log` shows the "commit log" http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log . And I wanted to get rid of two entries from that log - not the changes.

Answer (score 277, accepted):

[git-rebase(1)](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-rebase.html) does exactly that.

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

[git awsome-ness [git rebase --interactive]](http://web.archive.org/web/20100213104931/http://blog.madism.org/index.php/2007/09/09/138-git-awsome-ness-git-rebase-interactive) contains an example.

1. Don't use `git-rebase` on public (remote) commits.
2. Make sure your working directory is clean (`commit` or `stash` your current changes).
3. Run the above command. It launches your `$EDITOR`.
4. Replace `pick` before `C` and `D` by `squash`. It will meld C and D into B. If you want to delete a commit then just delete its line.

If you are lost, type:

```
$ git rebase --abort
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. So do I checkout A and do a rebase, something like `git rebase -i D [A]`?

Comment: @slhck: http://replay.web.archive.org/20090627051320/http://blog.madism.org/index.php/2007/09/09/138-git-awsome-ness-git-rebase-interactive

Comment: How can we do it on remote repos ?

Comment: @Eray: just `push -f` your changes. Don't do it if you're not working alone.

Comment: @nalply: [If you do, people will hate you, and you’ll be scorned by friends and family.](http://progit.org/book/ch3-6.html#the_perils_of_rebasing)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, thanks this makes sense. If we are a small team could we stop the world: everybody push, rebase, everybody delete local and clone? Would this work?

Comment: Updated link to use wayback machine.

Comment: @ripper234: I've fixed links to point `git-rebase` manual and wayback machine for the blog post.

Comment: <funfact> git rebase -i HEAD~5 followed by :q (from vim) results in --no-ff "Merge from..." commits being removed.  </funfact>

Comment: `@~5` is a shortcut for `HEAD~5`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I am genuinely wanting to delete a commit and all its data/changes, but when I remove the commit line that I want to delete and exit the $EDITOR with `:wq` all I get is a message that says `could not execute editor`. And them when I check under `git log` the commit I wanted to delete is still there. What does that error mean?

Comment: @MaggieB.: these questions: "how to delete a line in my $EDITOR, how to save the changes to disk, how to exit the editor, how to specify another editor that you are more familiar with" should be asked separately. The answers depends on your `$EDITOR` (don't forget to mention what it is).  See [ask]

Comment: Just to echo what @jfs said and add some more context, doing a rebase *will rewrite the log shas*! This is important to note, because if you've already pushed up, you'll need to force push to overwrite the upstream log. Problem there, as mentioned, anyone else working off that branch now can't push since the origin has changed. `git push --force-with-lease` is one thing to make note of, but in general, DON'T FORCE PUSH UNLESS YOU'RE WORKING ALONE!

Answer (score 76):

```
# detach head and move to D commit
git checkout <SHA1-for-D>

# move HEAD to A, but leave the index and working tree as for D
git reset --soft <SHA1-for-A>

# Redo the D commit re-using the commit message, but now on top of A
git commit -C <SHA1-for-D>

# Re-apply everything from the old D onwards onto this new place 
git rebase --onto HEAD <SHA1-for-D> master
```

Comment: This works too and helped me to understand what a soft reset is. Granted, the "top" answer is right too and shorter, but thanks for this answer as well.

Answer (score 41):

Here is a way to remove a specific commit id knowing only the commit id you would like to remove.

```
git rebase --onto commit-id^ commit-id
```

Note that this actually removes the change that was introduced by the commit.

Comment: The extra HEAD in this command is will cause the rebase to finish with a 'detached HEAD' which is undesirable. It should be ommitted.

Comment: This reverts the changes introduced my commit-id, the OP wants to retain the changes, just squash the commits.

Comment: -1 because it doesn't do what the OP asked (rather it destroys something he explicitly wanted to retain).

Comment: Although it doesn't do what the OP asked for, it was exactly what I needed, so +1 for a useful answer.

Answer (score 20):

To expand on J.F. Sebastian's answer:

You can use git-rebase to easily make all kinds of changes to your commit history.

After running git rebase --interactive you get the following in your $EDITOR:

```
pick 366eca1 This has a huge file
pick d975b30 delete foo
pick 121802a delete bar
# Rebase 57d0b28..121802a onto 57d0b28
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
```

You can move lines to change the order of commits and delete lines to remove that commit. Or you can add a command to combine (squash) two commits into a single commit (previous commit is the above commit), edit commits (what was changed), or reword commit messages.

I think pick just means that you want to leave that commit alone.

(Example is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327050/git-push-after-removing-large-file/2327928#2327928))

Answer (score 14):

You can non-interactively **remove** B and C in your example with:

```
git rebase --onto HEAD~5 HEAD~3 HEAD
```

or symbolically,

```
git rebase --onto A C HEAD
```

Note that the changes in B and C will *not* be in D; they will be *gone*.

Comment: See here for more info: https://sethrobertson.github.io/GitFixUm/fixup.html#remove_deep

Answer (score 3):

I find this process much safer and easier to understand by creating another branch from the SHA1 of A and cherry-picking the desired changes so I can make sure I'm satisfied with how this new branch looks. After that, it is easy to remove the old branch and rename the new one.

```
git checkout <SHA1 of A>
git log #verify looks good
git checkout -b rework
git cherry-pick <SHA1 of D>
....
git log #verify looks good
git branch -D <oldbranch>
git branch -m rework <oldbranch>
```

Comment: if you do this you will lose the E commit as well, won't you? As I understood, you delete master and rename rework as master (considering the ABCDE flow is the master branch).

Answer (score 3):

One more way,

```
git rebase -i ad0389efc1a79b1f9c4dd6061dca6edc1d5bb78a (C's hash)
and
git push origin master  -f
```

pick the hash that you want to use it as a base, and the above command should make it interactive so you can squash all the **top** messages ( you need to leave the oldest )

Answer (score 1):

Just collected all people's answers:(m new to git plz use it for reference only)

### git rebase to delete any commits

git log

```
-first check from which commit you want to rebase
```

git rebase -i HEAD~1

```
-Here i want to rebase on the second last commit- commit count starts from '1')
-this will open the command line editor (called vim editor i guess)
```

Then the screen will look something like this:

> pick 0c2236d Added new line.
>
> ## Rebase 2a1cd65..0c2236d onto 2a1cd65 (1 command)
>
> #
>
> ## Commands:
>
> ## p, pick = use commit
>
> ## r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
>
> ## e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
>
> ## s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
>
> ## f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
>
> ## x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
>
> ## d, drop = remove commit
>
> #
>
> ## These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
>
> #
>
> ## If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
>
> #
>
> ## However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
>
> #
>
> ## Note that empty commits are commented out ~                                                                                                                                                             ~
>
> ~
>   ~
>   ~
>   ~
>   ~
>   ~
>   ~
>   ~
>   ~

Here change the first line as per your need (using the commands listed above i.e. 'drop' to remove commit etc.)
Once done the editing press ':x' to save and exit editor(this is for vim editor only)

And then

git push

If its showing problem then you need to forcefully push the changes to remote(ITS VERY CRITICAL : dont force push if you are working in team)

git push -f origin

Answer (score -1):

You can use git cherry-pick for this. 'cherry-pick' will apply a commit onto the branch your on now.

then do

```
git rebase --hard <SHA1 of A>
```

then apply the D and E commits.

```
git cherry-pick <SHA1 of D>
git cherry-pick <SHA1 of E>
```

This will skip out the B and C commit. Having said that it might be impossible to apply the D commit to the branch without B, so YMMV.

Comment: The OP wants to combine B,C,D commits, not to delete their changes.

Comment: I think you meant `reset --hard`, not `rebase --hard` (which doesn't exist)