# Git: How to reset a remote Git repository to remove all commits?

Tags: git, version-control

How can I reset a remote and local Git repository to remove all commits?

I would like to start fresh with the current Head as the initial commit.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495345/git-removing-selected-commits-from-repository

Comment: I don't want to cherry pick or do anything else, I just want to remove all changes and reset the public repo also. As I am new Git user, I made some wrong commits. Removing .GIT directory is not an option as there is a public repository also.

Comment: You can do a force push also, so removing the .git dir is actually an option.

Comment: just nitpicking, but "revision" is an svn terminology and doesn't make much sense in a tree shaped history.

Comment: @TamásSzelei "Revision" is a perfectly acceptable synonym for "commit". It's used both in the Pro Git book (e.g. [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection)) and in the Git man pages.

Answer (score 433, accepted):

Completely reset?

1. Delete the `.git` directory locally.
2. Recreate the git repostory:

   ```
   $ cd (project-directory)
   $ git init
   $ (add some files)
   $ git add .
   $ git commit -m 'Initial commit'
   ```
3. Push to remote server, overwriting. Remember you're going to mess everyone else up doing this … you better be the only client.

   ```
   $ git remote add origin <url>
   $ git push --force --set-upstream origin master
   ```

Comment: +1 Was my first thought too. You have to backup and restore any local configs you have though.

Comment: Still in the remote repo at GitHub, in the messages I see previous messages.

Comment: but the commits are gone, and repository is reset. Can we remove those previous messages also in front of the filenames.

Comment: Remove the remote repository directly on GitHub and recreate it there.

Comment: Should be git push --force instead of git push -force

Comment: I recommend you do a copy of your repository first just in case.

Comment: If you don't want to commit any files in your "Initial commit", you can just not add any files, and add the `--allow-empty` flag at the end of `git commit -m 'Initial commit'`.

Comment: Using Git 2.3.2, I had to use ```git push --force --set-upstream origin master``` But all the rest was working as described

Answer (score 7):

First, follow the instructions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657017/git-squash-all-commits-into-a-single-commit) to squash everything to a single commit.
Then make a forced push to the remote:

```
$ git push origin +master
```

And optionally delete all other branches both locally and remotely:

```
$ git push origin :<branch>
$ git branch -d <branch>
```

Answer (score 3):

Were I you I would do something like this:

Before doing anything please **keep a copy** (better safe than sorry)

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b temp 
git reset --hard <sha-1 of your first commit> 
git add .
git commit -m 'Squash all commits in single one'
git push origin temp
```

After doing that you can delete other branches.

Result: You are going to have a branch with only 2 commits.

> Use `git log --oneline` to see your commits in a minimalistic way and to find SHA-1 for commits!

Comment: This is a great idea if you're not changing the remote origin