# Push to remote repo only file in current branch

Tags: git

I recently delete all file from current branch, with `rm --cached` command without delete `.git` folder. Then staged just one file in current branch. But when I try to push that file to remote repository, there seems other file also partake to transfer. 
I need to ask two question: 1. Is deleting file from current branch also delete that file from repository? 2. How just to transfer (`push`) file in current branch, not all file in repo.

[image]

Comment: 1. No 2. You don't push "files" but "changesets"

Comment: How to accomplish that?

Comment: to accomplish *what*?

Comment: Sorry, I dont fully understand, what you mean with changesets?

Comment: So I need to commit before to push that file?

Comment: you **cannot** push a file, you only push commits

Comment: Thats what i mean... is possible to push only the last commit. I mean in the last commit I deleta all file except one... so I need to push only commit about that file thereafter.

Comment: Don't you need the other commits at all?

Answer (score 0):

- 1/ Is deleting file from current branch also delete that file from repository?

  No.
- 2/ How just to transfer (push) file in current branch, not all file in repo.
  you will push all un-pushed commits, not just the last one

You can push only the current branch, with the [default push policy "simple"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21772695/6309).
Your first push should be

```
git push -u origin yourBranch
```

But that branch will include all the commits, including your last one (which reference only one file).

If you *really* want to reset the content of the remote upstream repo, you can have a look at "[How to reset a remote GIT repository to remove all commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2006172/6309)".