# how to compress all commit history into one commit?

Tags: git, github

So I've used the following:

```
git checkout --orphan newBranch
git add -A  # Add all files and commit them
git commit
git branch -D master  # Deletes the master branch
git branch -m master  # Rename the current branch to master
```

Which works quite well for Gitrepo commit history, however, when I use gitk --all I still see all of the prior commits. Is it possible to also merge all of these commits into one as well?

Thanks!

Comment: Just delete the .git directory and initialize a new repo.

Comment: how do i delete the .git directory? thanks

Comment: `rm -rf .git` should do it. See this answer here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006172/how-to-reset-a-remote-git-repository-to-remove-all-commits

Comment: Are you familiar with `git rebase`? That won't be destructive like deleting your repo would be.

Comment: "when I use gitk --all" -- That's not fair. If you check before force-pushing and replacing the remote `master`, then yes, you will still have a local reference to what the remote looked like the last time you synced.

Answer (score 3):

Use `git rebase -i --root`. 
Then change the prefix of all lines except first from `pick` to `squash`.
All commits will be merged in one single commit.

Of course, when you push your changes you'll need to force the push, otherwise it won't push your changes.

Comment: What does the `--root` switch do in this case?