# How to set the gitlab repository to the initial state

Tags: git, gitlab

So

1. I created a repository in gitlab
2. Pushed some changes to the master branch
3. Created many other branches and pushed changes to each of them too

Now I want to go back to the step 1 using command line, so basically an empty and initial repository that I had at step one, right after the repository creation with no history, nothing

Any way to do it in command line?

I tried many ways but not got succeed. Checked few stackoverflow posts too like this one but didn't work for my case

[How to reset a remote Git repository to remove all commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006172/how-to-reset-a-remote-git-repository-to-remove-all-commits/2006252)

https://gist.github.com/stephenhardy/5470814

Comment: Remove the directory and create a new one...?

Comment: @Paolo - That is the obvious way, but I do not want to do that because I have tons of repositories so I am looking for a way to reset existing repositories from command line

Comment: You can get fairly close with a very short script: list all references, then use `git push --delete` to delete them all. That's not guaranteed to be the same state as an initial empty repository, though.

Answer (score 1):

#### `rm -rf .git` then `git init`.

The `.git` directory holds all the commits, commit history and other metadata that make a repo a repo. When you delete the `.git` directory in a repo, it turns back into a regular directory.

Then you can do `git init` again like the very first time. Use `git add` to add your files and then `git commit` for you initial commit.

You will have to force push (`git push -f`) to Gitlab since you have essentially rewritten history from the remote's perspective. Alternatively you can delete the repo on Gitlab and create a fresh one. Then follow GitLab's instructions for pushing an existing repo to it.