# How to remove a versioned file retroactively in git/TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, version-control, tortoisegit, unfuddle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [git - remove file from the repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730411/git-remove-file-from-the-repository)

I just realised that my binaries have been version-controlled since I started my git repository, which has resulted in a `.git` of 10MB -- way too large for 40 revisions of a small project.

How can I retroactively remove these files from the repository? A simple git removal would not remove their history, so they would keep taking up space.

I'm using TortoiseGit with Unfuddle.

Comment: Found the answer but can't answer my own question. [Remove sensitive data](http://help.github.com/remove-sensitive-data/): `git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch -r bin'`

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730411/git-remove-file-from-the-repository

Comment: Why do you think you can't post the answer yourself? You should be able to...

Comment: @Jonas: "Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:

    Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 7 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead."

Comment: see also [git remove credentials from repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175881/git-remove-credentials-from-repository)

Answer (score 1):

This calls for `git filter-branch`. You will be able to get rid of the files you never intended on tracking.

Take a look here for more information:

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch

Hope this helps.