# Git how to removed selected commit from tree?

Tags: git, commit, rebase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Git: removing selected commits from repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495345/git-removing-selected-commits-from-repository)

I'd like to remove selected commmit from linear commit tree:

R->A->B->C->D->HEAD

I want to remove commit C and all changes which made in it.

Comment: Note that if you're content with just reverting the commit, not removing it, you can use `git revert`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using an [interactive rebase](http://book.git-scm.com/4_interactive_rebasing.html) operation. There's a good description of how it works in that link.

Essentially, you will rewrite commits so that instead of

```
R->A->B->C->D->HEAD
```

you have

```
R->A->B->D'->HEAD'
```

`D'` is related to `D` in that it introduces the same change, but is based on `B` instead of `C`. Note that if `D` introduces changes that depend on `C`, you may have a conflict you need to resolve.