# Git merge after hard reset of develop branch

Tags: git

Two branches 1. **Develop** 2. **Master**

The following are the commits of the two branches.

```
Develop -- 111x (was hard reset to remove the 112x commit) 
Master  -- 111x -- 112x
```

I'm trying to merge develop to master, but git says that it is already up to date. How to force merge in  this scenario?

Comment: merging develop into master will not pull in the reset that removed 112x, since master and develop both contain 111x they're already synced. if you want 112x _out_ of master, i recomment reverting that commit while master is checked out, then merging master into develop.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12305850/603742

Comment: @castis thank you, will have to do that manually