# Ignore Git commits when pull. Skip commits and continue from latest commit

Tags: git, repository, putty, git-bash, git-commit

I pushed the code twice on my repo and pulled it on the server, It had some issues so I had to go back and hard reset to a previous commit. Can I only get changes from last commit ?

Command I used to go back to commit 'C'

git reset --hard C

Visual representation:

commits on repo:

A-B-C-D-E-F

git on server side:

A-B-C'

Locally I only want to push some changes that are in commit 'F'. Now i want to pull changes only from the commit 'F' and skip 'D,E'. On server it tells me I am three commits behind and when I pull it gets files from all the commits. I only want files updated in 'F' commit or any other latest commit.

(Sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pull changes from F `git cherry-pick origin/F` then you need to push out your new changes. `git push -f origin`. This will remove D and E from your branch on the server side.

Comment: git cherry-pick origin/F gives me
 fatal: bad revision 'origin/F'

Comment: on local it displays head on 'F' and on server head is on 'C'. I used the reset command on server not on local, should i do something on local too ? Also I am on a single branch

Comment: Use git log to get SHAs of commits. `git log --oneline` add -n to limit number of commits. `git log -n 5 --oneline`. Now reset to C and cherry-pick F. `git reset --hard SHA_OF_C` and `git cherry-pick SHA_OF_F`

Comment: still gives me same message

fatal: bad revision 'F'

Comment: Use `git reflog` to get sha of F. It shows your commit history.

Comment: On local the command worked but on server it dose not work and on server the 'F' is not in the log

Comment: Okay so now any thing i push, I just run 'git pull' right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194239/discussion-between-aftab-ishfaq-and-encryptedwatermelon).

Answer (score 1):

**git reset --hard HEAD~1**

**git push -f**

(Example push: git push -f origin bugfix/bug123)

This will undo the last commit and push the updated history to the remote. You need
to pass the -f because you're replacing upstream history in the remote.

And if you want **revert or undo a no of commits** let's say 3 then the command will change like

**git reset --hard HEAD~3**

**git push -f**

[For more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459080/how-can-i-undo-a-git-commit-locally-and-on-a-remote-after-git-push)