# How is possible remove a directory with @ commit id

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a directory, called **stock** that I pushed in git which included a .git. When I view the the files in gitlab, there is another pointer **stock @625e9a3**. Is is possible to remove **stock @625e9a3**? How?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I undo a \`git commit\` locally and on a remote after \`git push\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459080/how-can-i-undo-a-git-commit-locally-and-on-a-remote-after-git-push)

Comment: Looks like a submodule. Does your project on gitlab contains a `.gitmodules` file?

Answer (score 0):

GitLab is displaying [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) with an `@ <sha>` next to the name.

If you want to remove the submodule from your repository, edit the file `.gitmodules` and remove the block

```
[submodule "stock"]
    path = stock
    url = ...
```

Comment: There is no .gitmodules in the repo. Where can I find it?

Comment: Okay. Could you please share a screenshot of this `stock @625e9a3` that you are viewing on GitLab? I would help us visualize what you want to achieve.