# To undo the last git commit push or the last 2

Tags: git, repo

How do we undo the last git commit push or the last 2 pushes, by the easy reference that number ? i.e. for example something like

```
git revert -n1
git revert -n2
git reset -n2
```

I'm quite git noob. Thanks

Comment: This question needs more information - you commited the changes, but did you push them? Do you want the files to be as they were before or keep the current state?

Comment: Looks like a dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459080/how-can-i-undo-a-git-commit-locally-and-on-a-remote-after-git-push

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this depends a lot on what exactly you want, but I'll give you some general information.

To actually undo a commit, you can use `git reset`. This will take your branch's HEAD and put it where it was 2 commits ago, keeping you files as they are now:

```
git reset HEAD~2 --soft
```

If you want the files to go back to how they were, you can use `--hard`:

```
git reset HEAD~2 --hard
```

Now, this is a bit problematic if you've already pushed your commits, because Git is supposed to only have commits added - never removed. So if you try to push a previous commit, you will receive an error saying you are behind the remote.

If you are sure you want that, you can force the change in the history by passing `--force` to `git push`. This can create a problem if you are collaborating with other people though: when they try to pull, if they already had the commits you are deleting, they will receive an error too, and will need to pass `--force` to `git pull`.

To allow reverting things without changing the commit history, `git revert` exists: it creates a new commit which does the opposite the reverted commit did. This will leave the changes in the commit log, but the actual files will be as they were before. If you want this, you can run:

```
git revert HEAD~2..HEAD
```

This will create reversal commits for `HEAD` (your last commit) and `HEAD~1` (your second to last commit), leaving the files as they were 2 commits ago. If you want to revert just a single commit, you can specify only that one. To revert just the latest commit you can use:

```
git revert HEAD
```

Answer (score -1):

git revert < your commit hash code >