# Git push to wrong branch

Tags: git

Working with git, after some 'commit', and a couple of 'push', I realized that am using the wrong branch!

Now I have to remove in some way my changes in `wrong_branch`
and commit and push the changes in `right_branch`

What's the best (and simple) way to do that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: removing selected commits from repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495345/git-removing-selected-commits-from-repository)

Comment: Good question @tokland: 99% of ruby developers use git, and the project I am working is in RoR ... but I know this could not be a good motivation

Comment: From my point of view, this is not a duplicate of what halfdan remarked, as it is also about moving commits to another branch, not only removing them.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

switch to that branch, check the `git log` and `git revert` those commits individually. Once you have done that, switch back to the desired branch and there you can then use `git cherry-pick` to pick specific commits from the git refs and merge it into the right branch.

```
git checkout wrong_branch
git revert commitsha1
git revert commitsha2
git checkout right_branch
git cherry-pick commitsha1
git cherry-pick commitsha2
```

If the commits are grouped together and there are no commits pushed after your dirty commits, you can even use `git reset` to get that wrong branch to a state just before your commits and then follow that again using `git cherry-pick` to get your commits into the right branch.

```
git checkout wrong_branch
git reset commitsha3 #commit just before commitsha2
git checkout right_branch
git cherry-pick commitsha1
git cherry-pick commitsha2
```

Comment: Revert + cherry-pick seems a lot simpler than other possible methods involving resetting head and/or rebasing.

Comment: For git cherry-pick you can put multiple shas in a single line, i.e. `git cherry-pick commitsha1 commitsha2`.

Comment: what happens when you want to merge wrong_branch (e.g. develop) into right_branch (e.g. feature/X) then you get the reverts undoing the changes you cherry picked in.

Comment: `revert` is so much cleaner and less dramatic than `reset` unless you really want to delete something sensitive (credentials?)

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is using `git rebase`. Suppose that you have that setting:

```
A -- B -- C -- C1 -- C2 # right branch
          \
           \-- D -- C3 -- C4 # wrong branch
```

You want to move change C3,C4 to the right branch.

```
git checkout -b new_wrong_branch D
git checkout wrong_branch
git rebase D --onto right_branch
git checkout right_branch
git merge right_branch wrong_branch
git branch -d wrong_branch
git branch rename new_wrong_branch wrong_branch
```

Now the setting is

```
A -- B -- C -- C1 -- C2 -- C3 -- C4 # right_branch
          \
           \ -- D # wrong_branch
```

Then you have to push your results with force (IF nobody has synchronized with your remote repo yet):

```
git push -f remote:right_branch
```

Comment: I've not tried this solution, I was already working out in the first answer (and it worked). I've not thought to at rebase, it looks like a good alternative, thank you

Comment: Rather than `git push -f`, better use `git push --force-with-lease`.
At least, it ensures that remote ref will be updated only if nobody pushed other commits on top of your commits.

Answer (score 2):

A bit of shortcut adding to Dhruva's answer

```
git checkout wrong_branch
git revert commitsha1

git checkout right_branch
git push right_branch

git checkout wrong_branch
git reset commitsha2 #commit just before commitsha1
git push wrong_branch -f
```

Answer (score -1):

I find flow this easier if the correct branch hasn't been created yet or doesnt have any new commits and is a direct child of the wrong branch:

- first delete right-branch if it already exists,
- git checkout right-branch
- git push right-branch
- git checkout wrong-branch
- git revert commitsha2 (or the commit before wrong commits)
- git push -f on wrong branch

and you have everything as if u never made any wrong commits in the first place.