# Remove commits from a single branch in Git

Tags: git, branch

I have two branches, master and feature1. I was working on feature1 when I realized that I needed to work on something else unrelated. Unfortunately, I forgot to branch from the master, and instead created my feature2 branch from feature1. Now I want to merge feature2 into master, but cannot because there are parts of feature1 in that branch.

How do I remove the feature1 commits from the feature2 branch? Does it involve rebasing?

I feel that if I could change the starting reference point of feature2 to be where master is, that might help, but have no idea how.

EDIT:

Thank you for the answers! I tried rebasing according to @Mark's solution, but realized that the history is more complicated than I originally thought. feature 2 has been merged into other feature branches, and master was merged into feature2 at one point. There are also additional commits on master that are not related to feature2 Everything is still local.

Really, my history is more like this:

```
A - B - C - D - - - - - - - - - - - - - L - M  master  
            |                          
            |               - I - J - K  feature2                  
            \              /           \
             - E - F - G - H - - - - - -N - O - P  feature1
```

And what I want is this:

```
A - B - C - D - - - - - - - - - -  L - M  master
            |\                          
            |  - - - - - I - J - K  feature2                  
            \                     \
              - E - F - G - H - - - N - O - P  feature1
```

I have also tried:

```
git rebase --onto 1524b824cfce5856a49e feature1 feature2
// 1524b824cfce5856a49e == D
```

But this just sets the branch name feature 2 pointing at 1524, and leaves commits I, J, K with their original parents.

Comment: Be careful if you're using a shared repository. If the commits you're trying to change are "pushed" somewhere you're going to run into problems when other people pull if you mess around with commit history. 

If you're using something like GitHub I don't think it will allow changes to the commit history.

Comment: Thanks for the warning! Luckily, everything is still local.

Comment: So you want `I` branched off of `D` and than merged back into `master` on the commit after `D`?  Unless I'm missing something, that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: No, that was me screwing up :) I actually want K merged back into master.

Comment: So basically all you want to do is remove E-F-G-H from _feature2_?

Comment: Yes. I want to keep the history of the two features separate, because feature2 is ready to be merged into master, but feature1 is not.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If it's only you working on your `feature2` branch and you haven't shared it with other people, it's fine to rebase that branch before merging.  You could do the following, for example:

```
git checkout feature2
git rebase --onto master feature1 feature2
```

... which will rewrite your `feature2` branch, leaving it so that it consists of all the commits in `feature2` since it was branched from `feature1`, but reapplied onto `master`.  I suggest you use `gitk --all` or a similar git history viewer afterwards to check that the result of this operation is what you want.

Incidentally, this is exactly the scenario used to explain `--onto` in the [`git rebase` documentation](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html#_description) - see the paragraph beginning:

> Here is how you would transplant a topic branch based on one branch to another, to pretend that you forked the topic branch from the latter branch, using rebase --onto.
>   [...]

---

*Updated in response to more material in the question:*

Starting with your history, which looks like this:

```
A - B - C - D - - - - - - - - - - - - - L - M  master  
            |                          
            |               - I - J - K  feature2                  
            \              /           \
             - E - F - G - H - - - - - -N - O - P  feature1
```

You can get what you want by doing the following:

```
git checkout feature2
git rebase --onto D H feature2
```

This will leave you with history that looks like:

```
A - B - C - D - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - L - M  master  
            |\
            | \ - I' J' K' feature2       I - J - K                    
            \                           /           \
             - - - - - - - E - F - G - H - - - - - -N - O - P  feature1
```

Before creating the merge that you want in `feature1`, you should note down the SHA1sum of `O` and `P`.  (I'm assuming `N` is just a normal merge, and not an "evil merge".)

Then do a hard reset to move feature1 back to `H`:

```
git checkout feature1
git rest --hard H
```

Then you should have the history:

```
A - B - C - D - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - L - M  master  
            |\
            | \ - I' J' K' feature2
            \
             - - - - - - - E - F - G - H feature1
```

Now you apparently want to merge `K'` into `feature1`:

```
git merge K'

A - B - C - D - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - L - M  master  
            |\
            | \ - I' - J' - - - - - - - K' feature2
            \                             \
             - - - - - - - E - F - G - H - Z feature1
```

And finally you can cherry-pick the old `O` and `P` onto `feature1` with:

```
git cherry-pick O
git cherry-pick P
```

... to leave:

```
A - B - C - D - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - L - M  master  
            |\
            | \ - I' - J' - - - - - - - K' feature2
            \                            \
             - - - - - - - E - F - G - H - Z - - O' - P' feature1
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I made an edit to add further details.

Comment: I looked at my history, and I was wrong in my diagram (now updated). feature2 is not merged into master. Nor is feature1.

Comment: !  If people are trying to help here, it's really important to get the information you post correct, otherwise you're just wasting their time.  Your question has undergone two revisions that totally changed its meaning, and thus the answer that would be required.  Regardless, I've updated my answer to match your third version...

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct, and I apologize. Initially, I wanted to keep the question simple, but in doing so oversimplified to the point where it no longer matched the situation. I also wasn't sure of what to actually ask, since I wasn't even sure of what path/tool would get me to what I wanted. Thank you for your patience and responses, they have been extremely thorough.

Comment: No problem, and sorry for being irritable.  Unfortunately, this kind of branch rewriting is really rather specific to the exact topology of the commit graph.  To be honest, once you're in that situation, I'd probably try to avoid this kind of rewriting, and just merge each branch back to master when they're in a working state that adds some new feature, even if the history is a bit tangled.

Comment: After playing with this for this long, I think I'm in agreement! But, you're answer was very helpful in understanding how I might go about fixing this. The actual topology is much more complicated than I described here.

Comment: `rebase --onto master feature1 feature2` was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much. Git rocks!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind that *feature2* is merged back in on `P` instead of  `M`, here is a relatively simple solution.

1. [Rebase](http://learn.github.com/p/rebasing.html) I-J-K onto D, *look at the section title "more interesting rebases*
2. Rebase O-P onto H. *same way as done in step 1*
3. Finally merge feature2 into *feature1* with `git merge feature2` while having *feature1* checked out.

If you want `K` merged into a particular commits, the rebasing gets a little trickier.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to rebase feature1 to remove the cherry-picked commits?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495345/git-removing-selected-commits-from-repository) is a SO question that answers how to do that.

Comment: I was initially wrong, in that neither feature1 or feature2 are merged into master. So this should be a bit more easy.

Comment: One more update with another solution based on your clarifications.