# how to undo commit

Tags: git, github, git-svn

Hi I want to undo my last commit. What I did is I made some changes to file then I commit them but I have not push them to main repo yet. After git commit -m "comment" command I ran git status and I got this message

```
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/demo' by 1 commit
```

So now I want to undo my last commit so how can I do that?

Comment: [Has been solved here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495345/git-removing-selected-commits-from-repository

Answer (score 17):

If you want to undo it completely:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

If you want to undo it and keep your changes staged (before commit):

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

If you want to undo it and keep your files modified (before stage):

```
git reset --mixed HEAD^
```

Comment: Could you please tell me what is HEAD here? Should I use the same command that you typed here?

Comment: HEAD is a file that always refer to the last commit on the current branch, OR if you have checked out a commit (in a detached HEAD state) its value is that commit. Yes, you should use the command as is, assuming you haven't switched branch etc.

Answer (score 1):

To revert your commit by creating another commit (assuming `master` is your working branch):

```
git revert master
```

To undo it, ie, pretend it never happened:

```
git reset --hard master~
```