# git: delete and forget of very old commits

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have a complex repository with some branches. All the branches have a common ancestor commit Z.

```
                  /..\                     branch4
A - B - C - Z -...............             branch1
              \....../                     branch2
                 \............             branch3
```

Some branches are fully merged in another branch, others are "dead forks".

Now I'd like to clean old history, removing and forgetting commits before Z, for every branches. The final result should be:

```
      /..\                     branch4
Z -...............             branch1
  \....../                     branch2
     \............             branch3
```

Comment: You can create a [shallow clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---depthltdepthgt) that gets only the commits that start from `Z`.

Comment: @axiac a shallow clone repository isn't a full repository. Could I work on a shallow clone repository as a full one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove / cut off Git's revision / commit history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687899/remove-cut-off-gits-revision-commit-history)

Comment: You can't have commit `Z` without parents. Commit `Z` has 1 parent, namely `C`. You can have commit `Z'` (a new commit that looks like the old `Z`, but doesn't have parents). All commit ids are going to change if you do this.

Comment: @knittl it could be fine to change all commit ids. Consider that this is a local private repo.

Comment: Why is this needed? Have you polluted the old history with binaries or something?

Comment: @Kim this repo is a copy of another repo when it was at commit Z. For this new repo, all the things before Z is useless and create misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3):

History in Git is permanent and can never be changed after the fact. What you can do is create a new history and stop using the old one.

Probably not a good idea (I would advise against it), but it's possible with the grafts file or the replace mechanism in combination with [filter-branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch):

```
git replace --graft Z # this will replace Z with a new commit that doesn't have any parents (but shares the same tree ref)
git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat -- --all # make the graft permanent and update tags
```

**NOTE**: This will change the commit ids (commit hashes) of *ALL* commits in your repository! If you are collaborating with peers on this repo, then everybody else needs to throw away their version and clone anew (or rebase all their branches).

Comment: This is ok for me, except that old tags are at old commits. I manually removed an re-create tags at new commits.

Comment: @pozzugno I have updated my answer to include updating of tags

Comment: `git replace --graft` does not seem to always work as intended https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77434651/git-replace-graft-not-truncating-commit-log?noredirect=1#comment136513888_77434651

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski everything works as expected: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77438638/112968

Answer (score 2):

If you need to squash all commit into a single one:

1. Run `git log --oneline` then write down the **A** commit hash.
2. `git rebase -i <commit-hash>`
3. Mark each commit by `squash`.
4. Exit the editor.

Instead if you want to drop old commits change step 3 from `squash` to `drop`.

**Remember that commits maybe part of many branches, so dropping them, remove them from any branch.**

In either scenarios you can customize the final commit message as you need.

Comment: This works rewriting the history of the current branch only and creating new commits that will be on the current branch only. I want that this effect will be applied to all the branches.

Comment: In such situation you have to sanitize each branch you need. It does not exist a git command which affects all the branches in a single shot.

Comment: @AntonioPetricca: not built in, but tools like git-filter-branch specialize in these kinds of mass manipulations.

Comment: Sure, but only fron DROPPING COMMITS. In such case another possibile solution would be https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/ , but unfortunately now I have not time to deal with its options. :)

Comment: I added some details about dropping into the main post.

Comment: This likely has the issue where if any conflicts were in history they would have to be re-resolved as git rebase applies commits one commit at a time...

Answer (score 1):

You could create a single commit on an orphan branch created from `Z` and then you could start *replaying*[1] branches on top of it.

[1] https://github.com/eantoranz/git-replay

And also read the `NOTE` on @knittl's answer because it applies anytime you are rewriting history.