# Dropping older Git commits from history?

Tags: git, git-svn

I have cloned an SVN repository into a Git repository, and I just want the last commits beginning from `f3a5b2a` commit. I do want to retain the changes, but they can be part of that `f3a5b2a` commit, I want to get rid of the unnecessary history because I don't need it anymore and I have the old SVN repository backed up.

There are commits spanning across 7 years, I just want the commits beginning from `f3a5b2a`.

Comment: I had asked a similar question sometime back - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495345/git-removing-selected-commit-log-entries-for-a-repository - The command you are probably looking for is `$ git rebase`

Comment: @xk0der I read that question, but it relies on interactive mode and there's no way I'm going to do that. There must be some other way.

Comment: Look at some of the answers below the one I accepted - specially the `--onto` switch seems to be what should help you. (1) http://stackoverflow.com/a/495526/29096 (2) http://stackoverflow.com/a/3705152/29096 - and a couple more in the thread.

Comment: Ah! I guess `--onto` removes stuff - This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/495526/29096 seems more appropriate for your need. Without having to go through the interactive mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a better way to clone an SVN repository and dropping older commits:

```
git svn clone -r1234:HEAD https://asdasd/ targetPath
```

It basically clones the given SVN repository, starting from revision 1234 until it hits the head.