# How do I get git branch history to match master after a squash rebase?

Tags: git, rebase, squash

Let's say I have the following tree structure:

```
A-B-C-D
    |\E-F (branch one)
     \G-H (branch two)

Master history: A-B-C-D
Branch one history: A-B-C-E-F
Branch two history: A-B-C-G-H
```

I want to squash commit B, so the respective histories should look like so:

```
A-C-D
A-C-E-F
A-C-G-H
```

I find out that, after I squash master, when I checkout branch one or two they still show the old history when I run git log. Does git copy the trees when branching? Do I need to rebase each branch individually?

Thanks

Comment: When you say "squash" do you mean `rebase --squash` ?

Comment: I tried with to squash with interactive rebase and alternatively by this method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495345/git-removing-selected-commit-log-entries-for-a-repository (second answer). Both yielded the same result, i.e. the need to rebase each branch separately.

Comment: Yes. No matter how you do it, you will have to do each branch separately. This is because each branch keeps its own history, and is unaffected by changes in other branches.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to rebase each branch individually. After removing commit B, you get

```
Master history: A-C'-D'
Branch one history: A-B-C-E-F
Branch two history: A-B-C-G-H
```

where C' and D' are like C and D except with B removed from the history. Branches one and two are unaffected by the master rebase. Another view of the result would be:

```
A-C'-D'
|\B-C-E-F (branch one)
 \B-C-G-H (branch two)
```

where A, not C, is now the closest common ancestor of all your branches.

Comment: Then, I think you will get what you want if you rebase your branches back on to `master`.

Comment: @willoller: Not quite, what you would get from a simple rebase is (for branch one) `A-C'-D'-B'-E'-F'`, and B wouldn't go away.

Comment: No I think `B` goes away in this case, since `C'` will contain `B` (since he squashed it, not removed it) making the history `A-C'-E'-F'`

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. It's unclear in the original question whether "want to squash commit B" actually means "combine B with C" (or maybe with A?), or "remove commit B entirely". I was assuming the latter, but your interpretation could be equally valid.