# Remove some commits in GIT

Tags: c#, .net, git

I am new to Git, although I just managed to change file in my previous commit.

[image]

First commit in redbox let's call it R1 is the one with commited password. I made it accidentally, so I wanted to make change - just change the file where that password was. I managed to do it successfully, not from the first time.

So I the commits the "path" to my head - last commit is the green box. These commits are same as the red one, but without the password.

So everything is as I wanted it to be, but I want to remove the 3 commits that are in a red box, cause password is still there.

Can you tell me how to do it?

I understand that this might be a duplicate, but I have a picture so maybe it will help to understand better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like what you may be looking for is `$ git rebase -i` which will bring up the interactive mode for rebasing your commits. In interactive mode you can edit, squash, discard previous commits. This is a previous discussion about using interactive rebasing. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495345/git-removing-selected-commit-log-entries-for-a-repository)

This should be enough to help you clear away the previous commits that contain the details that shouldn't be public.

In the future you can create a .gitignore file that will tell git to ignore certain files, which helps greatly with privacy and security issues. You can find more about .gitignore files [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

In the future if this occurs you can easily erase a commit by using `git reset --hard HEAD~1` which will bring you back to the commit before the head.

You can use `git log` at any time to find a specific id of a commit that you want to jump back to with `git reset --hard <sha1-commit-id>`, but be advised this will delete the changes at your local working level.

Comment: Note that this way the commits still remain in the repository (unreachable by any branch, but they still do exist) until they get garbage collected.