# how to delete commit entries in github?

Tags: windows, git, github, rebase

Trying to delete commit entries in my remote github repo. How can I keep the last 5 commits and delete the others? I tried this:

[How to remove selected commit log entries from a Git repository while keeping their changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495345/removing-selected-commit-log-entries-for-a-git-repository)

After 'git log' on my local machine it looks like I got the result but after 'git push origin' I checked my github and the older commits were still there?

Edit: I just tried this :

```
git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

The editor comes up , I close it. When I say 'git log' it did not reduce the number of commits to 5?

Comment: "The editor comes up , I close it" - You are supposed to edit it - set which commits you want to skip. Docs: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_interactive_mode

Answer (score 0):

You have to force-push:

```
git push -f origin
```

Comment: sorry I changed the question slightly appreciate the answer though