# How to remove Github commit history?

Tags: git, github

I have a private Github repo, in which I was using `.env` file. Now I want to make the repo public and I created a commit with removing the `.env` file so my commit history looks like:

```
my-repo [master●] % git log --oneline
71846d4 Remove env file.
0e28737 Add README file with some assets
f1f672a Stop tracking .env file
```

Now since I removed the `.env` content, the modifications still can be seen by checking `71846d4` commit.

Is there anyway I can just remove the commit so we won't be seeing the content of the changes there?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495345/how-to-remove-selected-commit-log-entries-from-a-git-repository-while-keeping-th probably this might help.

Comment: How about using squash? https://github.com/blog/2141-squash-your-commits