# How to delete commits with egit?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I just made some bad commits with egit that I would like to delete.

[image: Some bad commits I want to delete]

How do I delete commits from egit?

Thanks!

EDIT: I tried a hard reset a few times but it didn't do anything.
[image: Hard reset screen]

EDIT 2: Hard reset does rollback changes indeed, but I want them to completely disappear from the history as if I never made these commits.

Comment: Here is my explanation on how to do it with egit interactive rebase : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70754367/3139370

Answer (score 40):

RightMouse on your Repository and click on "show in -> history".
You should select the last commit before your last "fetch"...most of the time its the second commit under your current HEAD.
RightMouse on that commit and "reset -> Hard" (will reset all your commits AND local workspace changes to the selected commit).

you should see the up-arrow changing into an down-arrow, meaning that your commits are deleted and that your repository is outdated. Use "fetch" & "rebase" to be up to date.

Comment: "Fetch" fetches the remote repo in the local repo, and "rebase" asks for selecting another branch then the current branch... Didn't delete anything, only rolls back changes. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: seems so, because rebase would normaly "update" your "outdated" files in the local repo or launch the conflict manager tool. if my instruction dont work for you -> setup a new egit when you have only bad commits on your repo.

Comment: Note that this didn't work for me. It worked locally, but it wouldn't let me push this change to the central repository. It rejected it for "non-fast-forward". What ended up working, which isn't quite what the OP asked for, was "Revert Commit". It let me push that to the central repo.

Comment: 10 years later, this helped me

Answer (score 5):

Note that [Egit3.0 in Kepler](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/06/11/egit-3-0-top-eclipse-kepler-feature-9/) allows you to hard reset to any treeish expression you want:

[image]

But once hard reset, you still need to `git push --force` after that: if you don't the history of your upstream repo would still list that commit.