# EGit - "Replace With Commit..." doesn't work as excepted

Tags: java, eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, egit

I'm using **EGit** with **Eclipse Indigo SR 2 Build 20120216-1857**.

Almost everything works well, except the `Replace With -> Commit...` function. In fact it works, but doesn't restore the project exactly like it was because it left the new files that I added since.

It looks like it does a kind of a mix between current HEAD and the commit I choose to restore. **What I really want is to replace the content of my project with a previous commit like it does when you switch between branches.**

Is there any solution ? And does anyone knows if the lastest version of Eclipse provide a fully working version of EGit ?

Or am I misunderstanding this feature ?

Comment: You want to restore a previous state of the project? Permanently or temporarily? Or just a single file?

Comment: I just want to restore the content of my project from what it was in a previous commit. No matter I try on the whole project or on the **src** folder it doesn't work, or maybe I don't understand this feature, but *Replace With...* is self explanatory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@VonC pointed me towards one solution but that's not really what I want.

I tried the *Reset* command but first, I had to tag the commit to be able to choose it. Then it changes the whole `master` branch and canceled the next commits. In fact I don't want to change any branch or to delete any commits, I just want to be able to return to a previous one to see the whole code and eventually run it.

Finally I could have it to work using **Checkout** on the commit. To see all the commits : `Right click on your project -> Show In -> History`

It will not modify any branch your were working on but just replace the content of your project by the one the commit has saved.

Comment: +1. Cjeckout is indeed more appropriate than my "Reset" answer.

Answer (score 3):

The "`Replace with`" I know in Egit is **[about git checkout](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Reverting_Changes)** (and not `git revert`, as [robinst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/305973/robinst) [comments below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636040/egit-replace-with-commit-doesnt-work-as-excepted/14641324#comment20461552_14641324)).
And [checkout is not the same than reset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8358035/6309).

> What I really want is to replace the content of my project with a previous commit like it does when you switch between branches.

That would be closer to the **[feature "Reset"](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Resetting_your_current_HEAD)**.
Selecting the "hard reset" would remove any private file and completely restore both the index and the working tree to the selected commit.

[image: reset in Egit]

<sup>(from "[How to delete commits with Egit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534336/how-to-delete-commits-with-egit)")</sup>

> `hard` - the HEAD points now to the new commit, the index and the working tree are updated.

You also can see it in [this tutorial](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/tutorials/egit-tutorial/):

[image: reset in Egit bis]

Comment: It may be what I am looking for, but when I choose *Reset* I can only choose a branch, a ref or a tag but not a commit. Am I forced to tag the commit which I want to go to or is there another way ?

Comment: @miNde in that case, set a tag on the commit you want to reset to ;)

Comment: Ok thx it worked, but I got a problem using *Reset* because it made the master branch to delete all the commits made after the one I choose to reset from. But I don't want that, I just want to be able to return to a previous commit to see the whole code and eventually run it. Finally I could have it to work by using *Checkout* on the commit.

Comment: *Replace with* does not do a `git revert`, it corresponds to a `git checkout ref -- paths`. Revert is also available in EGit, but that creates a new commit with the changes reversed. Replace with changes the working directory.

Comment: @robinst good point. I have edited my answer to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Newly created files are not in git index (untracked) unless you add them into. Since you are reverting your workspace back to a commit, only your tracked files (added to git index) will be modified. Newly created files are not touched.

If you want to delete your untracked files:

`git clean -f -d` will do it.

Comment: When I said "new files" I was talking about files that have already been committed at least 1 time, not untracked files.