# EGit: How to restore git to to the clean state

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I read few threads on backing out commits. Following are relevant
[How to delete commits with egit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534336/how-to-delete-commits-with-egit)
[What's the difference between Git Revert, Checkout and Reset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358035/whats-the-difference-between-git-revert-checkout-and-reset)

But how do I revert/reset/restore back to clean original state. I just started working on new project and the original git directory structure got messed up after the first check in (because I incorrectly created git repository as eclipse project); this problem is discussed in "The short story" or "The longer story" of following link 
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Creating_Repositories

Now I wanted to restore the original directory structure of git repo. In History window, I see all the previous commits and I can right click on them and back out to one of previous commits; sadly the history window doesnt show anything to prior first check in (or commit). But I want to back out to the original directory structure that existed prior to first commit (that way I will have clean repo without any code base in it). It doesnt matter if it is restore/reset/revert as long as git repo looks same as it was before first committ. Can I do this in eclipse/egit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't something that Git would have kept track of.

You *might* look into the [Eclipse local history](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-55.htm) (which is separate from the history recorded by Git), but that is for a file only. Not a all structure.

It is best to recreate a Git repo, and make as a first commit your clean structure, before adding code base in it.

Answer (score 1):

Go to git perspecive-> Expand the repo. Right click on working tree. Clean. Finish. See the below pasted image link.

[clean  in git perspective](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqMAF.jpg)

Comment: This is what I needed.  In Eclipse 2023-06 I clicked Clean in the context menu on the repository, I did not need to go to Working Tree.