# Github Master became HEAD and I can no longer push upstream

Tags: eclipse, git

I have been using github for my latest project but something weird happened.  We messed up so we had to roll back.  To do this I used the check out command on the commit we wanted to roll back to.  Then I pushed that upstream.  But now my branch no longer says main and I can't figure out what to do.  My history is in the following link:
[History](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2o2t.png)

We rolled back to "Fixed, makes sense passing around Joe".  Now when I push it brings up a weird dialogue box that says "push branch in remote".  So, I was wondering if there was a command to make what I have on my computer the regular old Master branch.

EDIT:  One more thing, the basic pull (with out a ...) and the PUSH to upstream options are now grayed out in the team tab of eclipse.

Comment: Checking out a commit will put you into a detached state.   What do you see when you run command `git status` on the command line?

Comment: If Eclipse prints what commands it executed when you `pushed` the checked out branch, share that here (Try the console tab). That will help us understand what happened. To add to what @Todd said, when you checkout a single commit you are sort of in a no man's land. It is always better to checkout to a commit with a branch. That way you have a pointer to that point in history.

Answer (score 0):

Check in command line if a `git status` shows you a [detached HEAD situation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309).

You would need, with eclipse, [to hard reset your master branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13534336/6309) to the commit you want, in order to make sure it is not in that state.
But make sure your colleagues are aware of that because you might need to [force push](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27571408/6309) that (reset) branch and anyone working on  that repo would need to reset his/her own branch to the new history.