# How to remove and specific commit from Bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket

git rebase -i HEAD~x
(x= no. of commits)
upon executing notepad file will open 'put' drop besides your commit
git  push --force-with-lease.

When I add drop it says unknown command.

Please let me know I only want to remove an specific commit

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the second answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938301/remove-specific-commit), you could use `git revert --strategy resolve <commit>` where `<commit>` is the identifier of the commit to be reverted.

Comment: git revert --strategy resolve <commit> this thing deleted the files from my machine I want delete it from bitbucket account

Comment: Have you pushed the revert to the remote repository ?