# Can I remove previous commits from a branch?

Tags: git

This is a bit more complicated than previous threads I have found. Say I have a branch with a bunch of commits. At some point, I realized that I don't want some buried commits (which were caused by a misguided merge). So the history is something like this:

```
e48ca7de8t
a263f02809 --> unwanted commit
59d785a8e2 --> unwanted commit
2045cc737a
59c2a4127c
f9daf617sj
5f59c2a412
HEAD
```

Basically I would like to get rid of the two unwanted commits. Is this something that is possible to do?

I suppose I could keep doing `git reset HEAD~` over and over again until I reach what the ones I don't want, stash the changes remained and do a `git reset --hard` to whichever last one I want. But I wonder if there is a cleaner and safer way of doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: `git rebase -i HEAD~50` opens an editor with the previous 50 commits.  Delete the ones you don't want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1338758/635608

Comment: I've used `git rebase -i` in the past to delete commits.  Does this post help you? 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/40926981/464252

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `git rebase --onto` to rebase a series of commits onto a specific commit. For the above example (assuming the branch name is `mybranch`:

```
git rebase --onto 2045cc737a e48ca7de8t mybranch
```

This way the unwanted commits

```
a263f02809 --> unwanted commit
59d785a8e2 --> unwanted commit
```

are left out during rebasing.