# How to do an interactive rebase (rebase -i) on a mirrored repo

Tags: git, git-rebase

I am experiencing some issues when I try to do an interactive rebase on a repo created via a mirror.

Situation.  The original repo was created:

```
git clone --mirror https://github.com/dashboard3.0.git
```

However, a lot of garbage commits have gone into this mirrored repo (so it is NOT a mirror anymore).

Problem:
I tried doing a rebase using this link:
[Remove specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938301/remove-specific-commit)

But because this is a mirror repo, it did not work. Below are the steps I took.  I entered the command git `rebase -i HEAD~15`

[image]

And below is the error:
[image]

Any ideas on how to continue.  I am nervous to continue.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested, I resolved this issue, by taking a more aggressive approach.  I decided to reduce all my commits into 1 and start fresh.

I used these commands:

```
git log > original.log # Save git log history.
git checkout --orphan new-master master
git commit -m "New initial commit for the <insert repo here>."
git branch -M new-master master
git push origin -f
```