# is there anyway to delete or remove a git commit by specific commit id

Tags: git, github

l couldn't find a way to delete a commit and remove it from Github history and git log by **specific commit id**

Comment: You only want to remove a specific git commit? What is with `git log`?

Comment: @SwissCodeMen l made some useless commits l want them removed from git log where its track commits and in Github history l want to remove them like they were never committed

Comment: Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938301/remove-specific-commit)

Comment: @SwissCodeMen yes already did l couldn't find what I'm looking for is there something l missed ?

Comment: In Git, you can't "remove" a commit without re-writing all the commits that came after it. One way to rewrite commits is called `rebase`. The question @SwissCodeMen linked to has multiple ways to do it. The one you want is probably `git rebase -i ...` . The `-i` means "interactive" so that you tell it which commits to remove, by literally deleting the line, or changing "pick" to "drop" or "d".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the specific `commit-id`:

```
git rebase --onto commit-id^ commit-id
```

and then forcibly push to GitHub:

```
git push --force-with-lease
```

Read [git-rebase documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) and [git-push documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) for more information.