# Couldn't I just pick out the git commit history and delete it?

Tags: git, github, terminal, atlassian-sourcetree

I followed what I saw on the Internet to fill a field of grass on GitHub, but all the commits I've done have been doubled.

[image]

I want to get rid of the new cloned commits, what should I do?

As the number of commits in a repository doubled, the grass faded as a whole.

Can't I go back on this? I don't know the Git Terminal well, so I'd appreciate it if you could explain it in detail.

```
git filter-branch --env-filter \
    'if [ $GIT_COMMIT = {MY_HASH}]
     then
         export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="Tue Aug 4 11:00:00 2020 +0900"
         export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="Tue Aug 4 11:00:00 2020 +0900"
     fi'
```

```
git pull origin main --allow-unrelated-histories
 
git push origin main
```

I did it in the above way when I changed the date of the commit.

I've looked up a lot of blogs, but I can't get enough help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Find the commit ID of the last blue commit called `solve make_1`. Have you tried `git reset --head thecommitid`. Then do git push --force. If needed delete and recreate the repo and push just the blue branch.

Answer (score 0):

You can squash the commit for double the commits to a single...
or in case you want to specifically remove by commit id, look for the below another StackOverflow answer that might help you

[Link to the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21338314/13992417)

just don't want to give the same, so shared the same