# Removing Specific Commits and Merges Within a Range in Git

Tags: git, github

I want to remove several commits and merges from Git. For example, I have 10 commits before and 10 commits after the specific commit I want to remove. I want to delete 4 commits within this range. How can I achieve this?

Here is a picture for furder explination.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTRNY.jpg

This issue occurred when I was trying to amend the previous commit, which I had mistyped. Git prompted me to perform a merge, and this is what happened.

Comment: Have you tried rebasing? `git rebase -i <sha1>` where `<sha1>` is a commit you want to keep before the first one you want to remove, and then delete the ones you want to drop. By default, rebase will drop the merge commits too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938301/remove-specific-commit)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is git rebase interactive.

`git log --oneline` to see all list of commit

[image]

then Run below command

```
git rebase -i HEAD~x
```

Lets say I want to remove commit 3 and Commit 4 here., Mark commit 3 and commit 4 as drop.

[image]

specify x as the number of last commits which you wish to value as the commit which expect you wish to see and want to edit. If you specify 20, you will list of last 20 commits.

From the list mark which one you want to drop using

Once completed Esc --> :wq --> enter.
You may come across conflicts, resolve conflicts and once everything looks ok

```
git rebase --continue
```

[image]

Hope this helps.. Happy coding.