# git push heroku - stop heroku pushing/uploading massive file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, github

Having accidentally put a pretty large file which was not excluded by .gitignore in my working directory i committed my changes, pushed up to github then did a git push heroku up to production.

when i saw it was trying to push 100s of MB of data up to heroku, i killed the process.

I have since done a 
`git rm filename.extension` 
followed by 
`git add .`, a new commit and git push. But when i get to `git push heroku` it insists on continuing to push this impossibly large data file.

how can i check what the offending file is, and how can i make git/heroku forget it was ever there so git push heroku can start working again...?

Thanks!

Comment: Dont get the question, are you asking how to find that particular file or asking how to exclude a file from versioning?

Comment: in short, git push heroku keeps trying to push a big file that isn't there - in the directory or in git - anymore. I want it to stop doing that. confirming the file is the one i am thinking of, would simply help diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you did a `git rm large.file`, the commit introducing the `large.file` is still in the history of your repo.

To make git forget about the commit, you'll need to remove it from your repo's history. This could be done using `git rebase` as described in the answers to these questions (for example):

- [How do you remove a specific revision in the git history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37219/how-do-you-remove-a-specific-revision-in-the-git-history)
- [How to remove selected commit log entries from a Git repository while keeping their changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495345/git-removing-selected-commits-from-repository)

After you removed the commit from the history, you could `git push -f github` and then `git push -f heroku`.

**Note** that `git push -f` could cause problems if someone fetched the state of your github repo since your last push. See chapter *The Perils of Rebasing* in the [progit book](http://progit.org/book/ch3-6.html) for an explanation why.