# Cleaning up git history

Tags: git, github

In one of my projects (checked into a git repository) I have added a huge directory (15000 files, 3GB). When I realized this was wrong, I deleted it, but it seems like it is still in history.

Having it still there makes a project clone a very long task. Once the project is cloned, the .git directory is about 4GB but the real project size is just 15MB.

My question is: how can I tweak the history such as I make sure that 3GB directory is deleted? Or is there another way to decrease the entire project download size and speed up the clone process?

Comment: Just to clarify: The 3GB has been in the repository for a while, correct? The handling is different if it is not a very recent commit or if other people have already pulled commits made after the large one.

Comment: The dir was there for about a month. I deleted it another month ago. There may be a couple of files that were changed. There are only 2 developers on the project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove files from git repo completely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563564/remove-files-from-git-repo-completely)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you know which commit introduced the huge directory. Say this was done in revision `AAAAAAA`.

To get rid of the commit, it is not sufficcient to delete the directory (with commit `BBBBBBB`) and check in again: the commit `AAAAAAA` is still there, blowing up your repo size.

To get rid of the commit, we need [`git rebase`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-rebase). Open your git console and type

```
git rebase -i AAAAAAA~1
```

This will bring up an editor where the commit `AAAAAAA` is in the first line. Remove this line (i.e. when Vim is your editor, hit <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>) and the commit where you removed the directory again (`BBBBBBB`), save the file and quit (`:wqa`).

After this, rebasing starts and when it has finished, `AAAAAAA` and `BBBBBBB` are no longer there. Really.

You could now also trigger some housekeeping with [`git gc`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-gc) and fetch a cup of coffee while it's running.

---

See also this answer: [git push heroku - stop heroku pushing/uploading massive file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164419/git-push-heroku-stop-heroku-pushing-uploading-massive-file/9164896#9164896)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems like a good plan to me, but I have actually preferred to create a new repository, copy the code there and start from scratch. It was easier for me and at least I understood the process entirely :)

Comment: What does `-i` and `~1` mean?

Comment: @qed: -i means interactive ( see docs of rebase) and ~1 means 1 revision back ( https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try to follow this guide: http://book.git-scm.com/4_undoing_in_git_-_reset,_checkout_and_revert.html

Basically, you can do

`git reset --hard HEAD~1`

or

`git reset --hard [prev_commit]`