# Git resetting a branch

Tags: git

[image]

So, I made some changes and committed them in the second commit - "`wslanguagelabel - color changes`". These changes are now on master. I then started a new branch - `replies`.

However, I want to get rid of the changes in the second commit shown - "`wslanguagelabel - color changes`" - so that master now points to "`blocking - works`", and then keep working on the `replies` branch.

Here's my question: If I `hard reset` master to "`blocking - works`", will this cause problems when I eventually merge `replies`? This is where I don't understand git well enough, and what exactly goes on under the hood. I'm worried that `replies` will still have changes from the second commit, which I want to get rid of, but I'm not sure if my thinking there is correct.

---

BLAZ's answer below is correct for the simple case of removing the commit from the branch.

MU gives a more complete answer in the responses to my comments.

Comment: If you hard reset master to "blocking - works" it will remove the commit from master, but it does not change anything in the replies branch. The replies branch will still contain the SAME history. To remove "blocking - works" from both branches will require some combination of rebase (like Blaz suggests) or recreating the branch (as mu suggests).

Comment: I wanted to select all three, but had to go with the most descriptive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help: think of the green labels, `replies`, `master`, and `trishtext`, as just that: labels, on green sticky-notes or similar.

These green sticky-note labels are pasted onto the circles, which are the actual commits.

You can peel off a label and stick it on any other commit circle, at any time.

If a commit circle has *no* label, *and* is not connected directly to another labeled commit "above" it, it becomes "abandoned".  Eventually abandoned commits are garbage-collected.<sup>1</sup>  This gives you a chance to re-label them if you goof up, but it's best to think of them as gone, as they're kind of hard to find (`git reflog` helps find them, also `git log -g`, but it gets messy).

In all cases, the commits themselves—*not* the labels—make up the "commit graph".  Each commit permanently records its parent commits (two or more if a merge, but usually just one parent commit).  To see a commit sequence, git starts with a label like `master` or `replies`.  That names one specific commit.  Git looks at that commit and tells you something about it.  Then, it moves back to that commit's parent(s), moving "down the line" from `c1173c4` to `af211ba`, and tells you something about *that* commit, and so on.

---

Doing a rebase (as some have suggested) *copies* a series of commits.  Here's a similar sequence shown in text form (not as pretty, no colors, etc., but otherwise the same idea as the snippet you showed):

```
* 1f33fa6 (master) D
* 6cb155d C
* 170af7a B
| * 4396360 (branch) checkpoint: got to state X
| * ba1bdf2 checkpoint more work
| * ace0be9 begin work on feature
|/  
* c55985d A: first commit
```

I can now `git checkout branch`—this gets me commit `4396360` as my working tree—and then `git rebase master`.  What this does is *copy* the changes I made in the three "side branch" commits (basically, run `git diff` or `git show` on each one to compare it with its parent, to see what I changed each time) and attempt to make the same changes/commits on top of `1f33fa6`.

If this succeeds, the result is:

```
  * xxxxxxx (branch) checkpoint: got to state X
  * wwwwwww checkpoint more work
  * vvvvvvv begin work on feature
 /
* 1f33fa6 (master) D
* 6cb155d C
* 170af7a B
| * 4396360 [abandoned] checkpoint: got to state X
| * ba1bdf2 checkpoint more work
| * ace0be9 begin work on feature
|/  
* c55985d A: first commit
```

I drew the new ones in shifted-over like this to make them mirror the old ones; "git log" wouldn't shift them over, and they'd have real actual SHA-1 values as well, but this is to give you the idea.  I also kept the old commits, but marked them "abandoned", because they would be: after copying all the commits, git moves the label, `branch`, to mark the newest of the *new* ones, which means the *old* ones no longer have a label.

If I use `git rebase -i`, I can drop one or more of the original commits, and git will do its best to copy only the changes I keep.  The three old commits will still be there, but with no label, they are quite hard to find, and the new commits will omit the one(s) I dropped.

---

If you simply move labels about—this is (half of) what `git reset` does<sup>2</sup>—then you get no new copies of old commits, and no commits get changed.  It's just that the *labels* move.

You were asking about how this affect a future `git merge`; the answer to that is: "it depends".

What `git merge` does is sort of simple to describe, although the details get quite difficult sometimes.  A regular merge has two possibilities:

- "fast forward", or
- "true merge".

Git starts by looking at the current branch, and the commit that you give it.  Let's look at your current situation:

```
* c1173ca (replies) working
* af211ba (master, trishtext) wslanguagelabel - color changes
* d38eaad blocking - works
```

Let's say you `git checkout master`.  This puts you on branch `master`, which is also commit `af211ba`.  The contents of that commit go into your working tree.  Now say you use the commit `git merge replies`.  Git must resolve `replies` to a commit ID (`c1173ca`, in this case).  It then looks at the history of your current branch, `master`, and the history of the named commit, `c1173ca`.

The parent of `c1173ca` is `af211ba`.  That's your current commit!  "Wow, this is an easy merge," says git; "all I have to do is slide the label forward one commit, to `c1173ca`, and check out that version and I'll be all done!"  The result is this:

```
* c1173ca (master, replies) working
* af211ba (trishtext) wslanguagelabel - color changes
* d38eaad blocking - works
```

That's a "fast forward" merge.  Git says: the history of the thing you're merging-in connects straight back to the history of the current branch, so I can just slide the branch label forward across all those commits—in this case, the one commit—and I'm done.

Suppose you use `git reset` to "move the label back one step", though, so that you start here:

```
* c1173ca (replies) working
* af211ba (trishtext) wslanguagelabel - color changes
* d38eaad (master) blocking - works
```

If you now `git checkout master` and `git merge replies`, git has to go through the same process.  The history starting from `c1173ca` goes to `af211ba`, and then `af211ba` has `d38eaad` as its parent, and wow, hey, it's another easy case!  Git can once again do a fast-forward merge, sliding the label `master` forward (or upward) two nodes.

A "real merge" occurs when you have a situation where sliding the labels around won't do the trick.  For instance, in the graph I showed, `git merge branch` can't slide `master` around to point to commit `4396360`.  If it did, commits `170af7a`, `6cb155d`, and `1f33fa6` would be abandoned.  Instead, it has to do a real merge, producing a common working tree and making a two-parent commit (I drew this by hand, actual `git log --oneline --graph` etc output may differ slightly):

```
* (master) Merge branch 'branch'
|\
* | 1f33fa6 D
* | 6cb155d C
* | 170af7a B
| * 4396360 (branch) checkpoint: got to state X
| * ba1bdf2 checkpoint more work
| * ace0be9 begin work on feature
|/  
* c55985d A: first commit
```

Whether you get into such a situation depends on what commits you make.  (You can force git to make a real merge, a two-parent merge commit, even when fast-forward is possible, with `git merge --no-ff`, but if you need that you probably know why, already. :-) )

---

<sup>1</sup>Whenever you peel off a label, it leaves a bit of "residue" as it were (in the "reflog"), a sort of ghost-image saying "I was once labeled *`replies`*" (or whatever the label was).  It's after the reflog entries expire that the commit node really goes away.

<sup>2</sup>The other half is manipulation of the "index" or staging-area, and the third half—`git reset` has three halves :-)—is how `git reset --hard` throws away the current work tree and replaces it based on the commit you're resetting-to.  Only `--hard` does that; the other `git reset` modes mean "move the current branch label and/or fuss with the index/staging-area."

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking out a branch on the latest commit, and then resetting `HEAD`, you should checkout the branch `replies` at that specific commit itself, like below

```
git checkout -b replies <SHA_of_commit>
```

This way, your new branch will be at exactly the commit you need to be, and you won't have to do any hard resets on your `master` branch. The merge should also work seemlessly fine, unless you change the same set of code in the `replies` branch as you do in `master` branch in subsequent commits.

Comment: Clarification needed: The problem is, I have some changes in `replies` already that I want to keep, unrelated to recent changes in my `master` branch. If I perform what you suggest, that will just create a whole new `replies` branch, correct?

Comment: What are the changes, are those already committed? Also, have you made any further changes on your `master` branch?

Comment: The changes are already committed in `replies`. No further changes on `master`.

Comment: Yeah in that case the changes will be lost. Check out rebasing in git interactive mode [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37219/1860929) for that case.

Comment: Wait a minute - You want to delete that commit from your `master` branch, or from your `replies` branch?

Comment: I want to delete it from both branches, but also keep the branches separate for a bit and not merge `replies` just yet. So it appears I have two options - a rebase on both branches or a rebase on `replies` and a hard reset on `master`. Is that correct?

Comment: Well if you delete it from both branches, the changes will be lost forever. Do you want to delete it completely from history, or do you just want to delete it from `master`?

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure I want to delete them completely, but if I did want to keep them but not have them included in neither `master` nor `replies` at the moment, I guess that involves: 1. Rebase `replies` -- 2. Get `head` of `master` to `blocking - works` -- 3. Spin off `wslanguagelabel - color changes` into a separate branch? ... Thanks, BTW.

Comment: @Ramsel Do those steps in order `3, 2, 1` or `3, 1, 2` instead of `1, 2, 3` and you should be fine. Step 3 is the backup step, it preserves the state of master branch as is right now, and hence it needs to be performed before the master branch is altered. In fact, if you are not confident enough, create another dummy branch from your `replies` branch so that you know that the state of that is also preserved. You can always delete the local dummy branches later.

Comment: @Ramsel Don't forget to accept an answer. If need be, you can post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Branch `replies` will retain the changes from the second commit. You could
selectively remove the second commit from its history with:

```
git checkout replies
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

where you delete the line with the second commit.