# Git: obliterating a specific commit while keeping following commits

Tags: git

How can I obliterate a commit, but keep subsequent commits intact?

In this scenario, suppose I want to get rid of `b` but keep `c`.

```
$ git init
$ for i in a b c; do date >$i; git add $i; git commit -m add-$i;done
$ git log
commit 39c976fa711b38d4c8161af9b6b4a9a91489d079
add-c
commit 2913863926f8c3a3898a2763fe4384b6ca7227a0
add-b
commit ff591ea43a84069e5effd28125b56243dc264336
add-a
```

doing a `reset --hard` will get rid of `b`, but also gets rid of `c`.

```
git reset --hard ff591e
HEAD is now at ff591ea add-a
```

How can I perform this operation while keeping the `add-c` commit intact?

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37219/how-do-you-remove-a-specific-revision-in-the-git-history

Comment: exactly. `git rebase -i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep everything in tact (is the sha1 of the commit ) you would do a `git revert b` where b is the sha1 of b. This adds another commit negating the effect of b

To remove b from history `git rebase -i b^`

Again where b is the sha1 of the commit

Then delete the line save and close

I would suggest the first way if there is anyone else working on the same repo

Comment: `git revert b` leaves `b` in the history for all to see. That's not what's normally meant by "obliterate".

Comment: Updated though I disagree history should exist