# Why did my rebase not do anything?

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

This project has only a `master` branch, so all work is being done there.

I mistakenly committed a typo, and while I could commit an undo, I thought I'd try just removing the commit altogether.

The commit hash is `dbcbf96b`, and `ded82215` is the commit right before it. So, working from [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37219/how-do-you-remove-a-specific-revision-in-the-git-history), I did this:

1. `git rebase -i ded82215`
2. This brought up the "todo" list in an editor, containing only the following, as expected:

   ```
   pick dbcbf96 Writer update.
   ```
3. Presumably following the instructions in the comments of that generated file, I changed that line to:

   ```
   drop dbcbf96 Writer update.
   ```
4. I saved the file and closed the editor. It then said:

   ```
   Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.
   ```
5. I then checked on GitLab (what I'm using to host this) expecting to see the commit gone, but it was not, it was still there.
6. I did `git status` to see what action it recommended and it yielded:

   ```
   On branch master
   Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
     (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
   nothing to commit, working tree clean
   ```
7. That kinda makes sense, but as for the rebase, I'm not sure what happened. Now I did `git pull` to update the local repo but it was all just right back where I started, right back at `dbcbf96b` with the local file still containing the change, the local repo up to date, and GitLab still showing the revision. The `pull` command yielded:

   ```
   Updating ded8221..dbcbf96
   ```

So my rebase attempt did nothing at all. What did I miss here?

---

So I tried `git push -f` between steps 4 and 5 as recommended by the answer below and it failed, yielding:

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to force push code to a protected branch on this project.
To https://gitlab.com/...
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.com/...'
```

I then tried `git push` just for grins and it also failed, yielding:

```
To https://gitlab.com/...
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.com/...'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

That kind of makes sense, too, I suppose that's what `-f` is for. The hints in the second bit again recommended `git pull`, which I already know isn't the right action here.

Comment: no `push` done (between point 4 and 5 ) ?

Comment: @nos No... I usually follow the recommendations of `git status` but it didn't recommend a `push` so I didn't do it. I'll try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git is built to *add new stuff* (where "stuff" means "commits") rather than to *take away stuff*.  That's why you must use a force-push: your push would "take away stuff", i.e., drop your commit.

You gave your rebase an explicit instruction, "drop this commit", so it did (with a bunch of airbags and safety belts that let you restore it, usually for at least 30 days).  A regular `git push` won't let you drop a commit; only a force push can.

*Because* a force push can lose commits, some servers offer a "protected branch" mode where some/many/all people are disallowed from force-pushing at all.  This is what you have encountered now.  To successfully force-push, you must set yourself up as allowed to do it—usually, by temporarily unprotecting the branch, then re-protecting it after the push.

#### Discussion

Make sure you are not dropping anyone *else's* commits at the same time!  Branch names are, in effect, just labels on commits.  It's the commits themselves that form the history-of-commits in a repository.  Each commit has, inside itself, the ID of its *parent* commit.  We say that each commit "points back to" its parent:

```
... <- commit 1234567   <-- branch
```

To add new commits, Git simply advances the branch "forward" (even though all the internal Git arrows point "backwards") to the newer commit.  For instance if we start with:

```
... <-B <-C   <--branch
```

we add new commit `D` by making a `D` that points to `C`, then making the name `branch` point to `D`:

```
... <- B <- C <- D   <--branch
```

To drop the `D`, we make `branch` point to `C` again, but if someone else has come along and made new commit `E`, the picture now looks like this:

```
...--B--C--D--E   <-- branch
```

When we now force `branch` to point to `C` instead, *both* `D` *and* `E` are lost:

```
...--B--C        <-- branch
         \
          D--E   [abandoned]
```

With `git push`, this is (almost) all you can do.  (There is one safety-belt available, called a "force with lease", where you have your Git tell their Git: "I believe your name `branch` points to commit `D`.  If so, force it to point to `C` instead.  If not, give me an error."  But there's nothing fancier, as their is within your own repository.  In *your own* repository, `git rebase -i` offers the ability to *copy* selected commits to *new*, but different, commits, so that you can drop intermediates.  `git push` has only the force options.)

Because of these, Git also offers the ability to "reverse" a commit: take some existing commit, figure out what it did, and do exactly the opposite—put back any file that was removed; remove any file that was added; remove lines added and add lines removed—as a *new* commit.  You can therefore back out any older commit in a newer commit, and this merely *adds on* to the history.  For instance, if, in the:

```
A--B--C--D--E
```

sequence, we find that `B` was bad, we can tell Git "make a new commit `F` that is the reverse of `B`", giving:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F
```

which "does the same thing" as if we never had either `B` *or* `F` in the sequence, but does so without having to disturb `C` through `E`.  The command that backs out an entire commit by adding its reversal is `git revert`.

#### An easy way to think about all this

Your own Git repository is just that: *yours*.  You can do anything you want to it, including dropping (abandoning) commits at the end of a chain, or copying commits (via `git rebase`) to drop intermediates by copying all the commits *past* that point.  This lets you "edit your history".

But, each of these commits has a unique ID.  That's the big ugly hash ID Git shows you from time to time.  The unique ID is a cryptographic checksum of everything that *went into* the commit—so "editing history" results in all-new IDs.  Gits exchange (push and fetch) commits by their *IDs*, so once you make your commits available to *another* Git instance—such as with `git push`—you have *published* those commits.  You can attempt to "un-publish" them, but with who knows what success.  It's a bit like trying to delete a tweet: someone probably already captured it.

This doesn't mean "never try to change published history", just "be aware that if you do try to change published history, it might not work, and anyone who's started to *use* that published history may be annoyed."

Comment: This is an absolutely stellar answer, and the whole thing makes a lot more sense to me now.

Answer (score 5):

> So my rebase attempt did nothing at all. What did I miss here?

That's not true, it definitely did do something.

You rebased your *local* repo, which doesn't do anything to the remote one on GitLab. So the remote one still has the unwanted commit, and when you `git pull` you fetch it and merge it back into your local repo.

After the rebase you would have needed to do a `git push -f` to force-push the altered local repo to GitLab, to remove the bad commit in both repos.

Comment: Hm, thanks, weird that `git status` didn't recommend that. Anyways, that failed too (*"You are not allowed to force push code to a protected branch"* -- see update in question). Perhaps a permissions problem with `-f`? I also tried just `git push` without the force flag and that failed for different reasons, although I assume that's why the `-f`. If it's a permissions error I'll do some further investigation, seems like a separate topic.

Comment: git doesn't recommend that, because if someone else have already pulled down the earlier  commit which you are going to erase, you severely mess with their view/history of the repository. Even more so if they created a branch from that to-be-deleted commit. And you get the error message because your branch has been configured as a protected branch (presumably to prevent the issues I mentioned).

Comment: You can't just rely on `git status` to tell you what to do, especially if you're doing potentially "dangerous" things like rebasing.