# What is the best way to take out the second and fourth commit?

Tags: git

In the git history, I have a branch with 5 file changes. On each change has it's own commit, this means I end up having 5 commit's.

What is the best way to take out the second and fourth commit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you remove a specific revision in the git history?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37219/how-do-you-remove-a-specific-revision-in-the-git-history)

Comment: Do you mean you don't want the changes from the 2nd and 4th commit, or that you want all the changes but want the history to have only 3 commits?

Comment: thank you , i don't want the changes

Comment: Interactive rebase, remove those commits from the list that shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `git rebase -i HEAD^6`. This will show a list of the last five commits along with their messages. Delete the lines with the commits that you don't want, save and quit the editor.

You may have some conflicts to resolve, but when you are done, your branch will contain three of the five commits.