# Removing sensible data from git history: removing a given directory, which is a submodule

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

I made a "git add dir" and then committed and pushed. Then I realized it was best to not add the directory to the repository, so I deleted it with "git rm -r". However, I want to delete it from the history, so that it cannot be recovered from the git repository.

I have looked at BFG Repo Cleaner, but

1. for some reason the directory has been added as a submodule to git: it has a .git subdirectory and in the logs it shows "Subproject commit 72ab72...". Can BFG Repo Cleaner remove this submodule?
2. BFG does not seem to support removing a given directory. --delete-folders takes a glob as a parameter, and since the directory has a common name it may remove other directories too.

What should I do?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067848/remove-folder-and-its-contents-from-git-githubs-history

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove folder and its contents from git/GitHub's history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067848/remove-folder-and-its-contents-from-git-githubs-history)

Comment: @miqdadamirali I used the guide "filter-branch" of https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/ It is similar to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32886427/7092558 Should I flag my question as duplicate or write an answer pointing to help.github.com?

Answer (score 0):

If it's the last commit that you'd like the remove you can

```
git reset HEAD
```

If you find that you need to go further, you'll need to either rebase or cherry pick. This is asked [very](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37219/how-do-you-remove-a-specific-revision-in-the-git-history) [often](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495345/how-to-remove-selected-commit-log-entries-from-a-git-repository-while-keeping-th?noredirect=1&lq=1) [on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository) [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/reset-or-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git?rq=1) but if there's a reason those answers don't help feel free to modify your question!